# Logs are not send to logentries from aws ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, logentries

We are using log-entries as driver on AWS ECS service for sending logs to our logentries account. We have configured AWS ECS service with required parameters like logentries-token but it's observed that after certain amount of time certain containers are not able to send logs to logentries.

Appreciate your help in advance, I am unable to find proper documentation for this on both logenries as well as AWS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, so I started digging deeper than usual.

[Actual driver implementation](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/9a2c26374393e0f46e8f2b1e49d2dcf66b78dbb4/daemon/logger/logentries/logentries.go) is quite simple.

The dragon is a [dependency that does the socket, tls handling](https://github.com/bsphere/le_go)

There is a [open issue and a PR to solve a very similar issue](https://github.com/bsphere/le_go/pull/13).

The PR is stale and I don't see chance for it to land, so I move away from logentries and recommend doing the same. Probably cloudwatch will be better.